# Using Windows Server 2008 R2 and PfSense

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, pfsense, dhcp-server

Hey I want to setup my personal home network so that R2 is dishing out DHCP and currently my PfSense box is doing this for me. my setup is motorola surfboard to PfSense to switch.

How do I configure PfSense so it does not give IP addesses to the network? Yes I could just use my Linksys router as the router and disable DHCP but wheres the fun in that right now my Linksys router is nothing more than a wireless AP with PfSense being the router. But I want my server to be the one who hands out IP addresses. I have tried looking through forums on this to find an answer but I am not having much luck.

So what all do i need to do to PfSense so that it is only a firewall and let server be the router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to rewrite a bad answer.

ErikA's suggestion makes sense in that if the pfSense fails, you will have no access to the internet so if you also have no DHCP your machines were pretty useless anyway.

However, I often prefer to use windows server because there is much more configurability.

If you wish to set up a resilient windows DHCP server this can be done.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd296672(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: pfSense uses DNSMasq for it's DHCP server, DNSMasq is very configurable.  I've never used Windows' DHCP server, but pfSense has supported both iSCSI booting and PXE booting as well as chain loading iPXE...

Answer (score 1):

Just disable the DHCP server on the pfSense box and enable it on the server.. It's under the "Services" menu in pfSense.

My question is: why do you want to do this? The DHCP Service provided by pfSense is very good, and by using it for your core infrastructure, you don't need to worry about a crashed server rendering your network useless.

Regarding makIng your server the router - you really really dont want to do that unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: Well ok it has been a good year since I have had a chance to play with Windows Server and I have been setting everything up by memory aka dcpromo setting up static ip addresses and all but Im having issues getting my Windows Servers in Hyper V internet connectivity. last time when i set this up i did not have PfSense so I was thinking that could be the cause as to why however if you think using PfSense for DHCP would be the better option then ill stick with that.

Comment: also in reguards to your last comment i do have a degree in computer networking :)